# colocar no html o resultado de cada iteração do ciclo for

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Se me pudessem ajudar aqui numa questão agradecia imensamente! Então, sou muito junior em javascript e estou a fazer um exercicio, em que queria colocar os resultados do meu ciclo for a aparecer no HTML, mas não estou a chega lá.

Basicamente, eu recebo dois valores como input e um deles é o custo do primeiro dia de ferias ao qual eu quero adicionar 20% depois a cada dia.

```js
const cost = document.querySelector(".input1");
const days = document.querySelector(".input2")
const btnConvert = document.querySelector(".btn-converter");

function calculoDespesaViagem(cost, days) {
  days = [];
  const percentage = 1.2;
  let maxDays= days.length -1

  for (let i = 1; i < maxDays; i++) {

    cost = cost * percentage;
  

    document.getElementByClassName("li").innerHTML = (` valor do dia ${i + 1}: ${cost}`);
  }

return cost;

}

btnConvert.addEventListener('click', function () {
  calculoDespesaViagem(cost.value, days.value);
});
```

```html
  <section class="container">
      <h1>Exercícios</h1>

      <label class="label"
        >Valor do primeiro dia de viagem
        <input type="number" value="50" class="input1" />
      </label>
      <label class="label"
        > Total de dias de viagem
        <input type="number" value="4" class="input2" />
      </label>

      <button class="btn btn-converter" id="btn-converter">Calcular Custos</button>

     <ul class="list">
       <li class="li"></li>
     </ul>
      <!--<h2 class="total" id="h2"></h2>-->
    
    </section>
```

basicamente eu pretendia por a aparecer no html mais ou menos isto:

valor do dia 1: 60

valor do dia 2: 72

valor do dia 3: 86.39

valor do dia 4: 103.68

...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá,

O problema está em dois lugares:

1. Você está criando uma nova variável 'days'. Ela é um vetor vazio, retornando length = 0;
2. A maneira de criar os elementos está errada.

```js
const cost = document.querySelector(".input1");
const days = document.querySelector(".input2")
const btnConvert = document.querySelector(".btn-converter");

//mudeio o nome da variável 'days'
function calculoDespesaViagem(cost, nDays) {
  //days = []; isso aqui tá fazendo com que a entrada no for não aconteça problema 1
  const percentage = 1.2;
  let maxDays= days.length -1

  for (let i = 1; i < nDays; i++) {

cost = cost * percentage;
//problema 2 está por aqui 
valor = ` valor do dia ${i+1}: ${cost.toFixed(2)}`
//criando um elemento HTML para o LI
li = document.createElement("li");
li.innerText = valor;
//Anexando no UL existente
ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0]
ul.appendChild(li);

  }

return cost;

}

btnConvert.addEventListener('click', function () {
  calculoDespesaViagem(cost.value, days.value);
});
```

```html
  <section class="container">
      <h1>Exercícios</h1>

      <label class="label"
        >Valor do primeiro dia de viagem
        <input type="number" value="50" class="input1" />
      </label>
      <label class="label"
        > Total de dias de viagem
        <input type="number" value="4" class="input2" />
      </label>

      <button class="btn btn-converter" id="btn-converter">Calcular Custos</button>

     <ul class="list">
       <li class="li"></li>
     </ul>
      <!--<h2 class="total" id="h2"></h2>-->
    
    </section>
```

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigada pela ajuda ! :)

Comment: Dispnha... Estamos aqui para isso ;)